# Limit G Suite Outgoing mail to N recipient

Tags: regex, email, routes, google-workspace

I'm trying to create a routing rule, which through a regular expression can block the sending of an email if the recipients (To: Cc: and Bcc :) exceed a certain limit

e.g.

```
(^To:(.*@.*)+(\n|\r\n|\r)|^Cc:(.*@.*)(\n|\r\n|\r)|^Bcc:(.*@.*)(\n|\r\n|\r)){4,}

MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 2 Dec 2019 18:51:05 +0100
Message-ID: <msgID-00000-11111-22222A@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Test
From: Name <email@example.com>
To: Name <email@example.com>, Name <email@example.com>
Cc: Name <email@example.com>
Bcc: Name <email@example.com>
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="00000000000046fe3e0598bc3916"
```

the problem of this regular expression is that the count of occurrences limited to the fields: To, Cc and Ccn stops at the first value found in each row, 
so it would only match if I change to {3,}

I can not however count email addresses in a header without limiting to those fields, otherwise I could find several email addresses scattered in the header, like msgId, inside the body or in the signature

Comment: What  _limit_ is it of? Give an example.

Comment: This will put a cap of 5 emails per To/Cc/Bcc line. It requires all three lines to be in succession. It can be changed as needed. `(?m)(?:^To:(?:[^@\r\n]*@){0,5}[^@\r\n]*\s*|^Cc:(?:[^@\r\n]*@){0,5}[^@\r\n]*\s*|^Bcc:(?:[^@\r\n]*@){0,5}[^@\r\n]*\s*){3}`

Comment: Also, the only way to _count_ the total number of email addr. , and thereby limiting them is to do it in 2 steps. First, capture / match those lines `(?m)((?:^To:.*\s*|^Cc:.*\s*|^Bcc:.*\s*){3})` then count the number of @ in that string.

Comment: unfortunately with the routing rules of G Suite I can't do it in two steps

Comment: the limit I have to set at this time is 20 recipients, the count must be unique for all 3 fields - To: Cc: and Bcc:, so that the rule blocks in each case outgoing mail with more than 20 recipients regardless of where they are